# ASP Mvc 3 wont autobind from JSON post request

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have got a simple controller:

```
public class UserCredentials
{
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public string Password {get;set;}
}

public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Authenticate(UserCredentials credentials)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And a simple bit of Jquery:

```
var credentials = {
    Username: "test",
    Password: "test"
};

$("#send-request").button().click(function() {
    var ajaxOptions = {
        url: "http://localhost:29097/authentication/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) { $("#result").html(result); }
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
});
```

Whenever I click the button on the page to send over the request, the UserCredentials object contains null for both properties... I have tried posting directly via fiddler with JSON, no luck there either... do I need to do anything special to get this working?

-- EDIT --

I have been double checking and it seems that when the data leaves the client it has the json data correctly within the header. However when fiddler picks it up it doesn't seem to contain the data, it looks like it is doing an OPTIONS call:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:29097/authentication/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:29097
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
```

If it helps I am running the MVC app via the Development Server (think its called Cassini)

Comment: what happens if you don't call Json.stringigy and directly send credentials object in jquery post

Comment: Same thing, tried with and without... although when I use the stringify. The data in the ajax request in js looks like:  "{"Username":"Test", "Password":"Test"}" and I have tried using single quotations in my JS but it still comes out as the above, and that seems like it should be invalid due to the extra double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing this JSON on client side.

```
var credentials = { "credentials": { "UserName": "test", "Password": "test" } };
```

Call the jquery ajax **exactly** like you did above.

When constructing JSON on client side, you have to take into consideration the **parameter** you have in your server side, in this case it is **credentials** on this line:

```
public ActionResult Authenticate(UserCredentials credentials)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you send the POST request - it must be a key value collection. It's not possible to view what JSON.stringify(credentials) does but it will be much easier to resolve your issue by using http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/. This tool will show you all the details for the request you are sending.

Comment: That seems no different to firebug's net panel or fiddler... As i said I have already tried sending the data directly from fiddler without the use of JSON.stringify but its not working there either. Also isnt the Json provided above Key/Value anyway Username, Password being keys, "test","test" being values?

Comment: Ok. now we know that your javascript sends something to the server but as u said this is not POST request (that's why your credentials at server side are null). For testing proposes please add [HttpPost] attribute to action, change argument from UserCredentials to FormCollection, try $.ajax({
 url: '...', type: 'POST'
 data: {...},
 success: function (response) {alert(response)},
});